# How to limit the content coming from wordpress shortcodes?

Tags: php, shortcode, xml

I am working on a wordpress shortcodes in which I want to the limit the content coming from a xml.

The code which I have used for wordpress shortcodes is:

```
function podcast_func( $content = null ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/FZ8yNTef.js"></script>
<center><div id="podcast" align="center"></div></center> 
<script> 
var PodcastplayerInstance = jwplayer("podcast"); 
PodcastplayerInstance.setup({ 
  playlist: "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml", 
  androidhls: true, 
  preload: "auto", 
  height: 200, 
  width: 400,
  visualplaylist:false,
  stretching: "fill",
    "plugins": {
        "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/listy.js":{},
        'viral-2': {'oncomplete':'False','onpause':'False','functions':'All'}
    }
});
</script> 
<?PHP
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'podcast', 'podcast_func' );
```

On using this `<div class="today-podcast" style="text-align: center;">[podcast]</div>`, it displays the entire content from here http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml

**Problem Statement:** I am wondering what changes I should make in the wordpress shortcode above so that it displays only 1st two items from here http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml

Comment: That's an external xml file. You will need to parse the xml file and instead of sending the entire unfiltered xml file URL as the value into the jwplayer, you can pass the parsed playlist as a JSON object like this: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#playlist

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thanks for the comment. I am wondering if you can let me know in an answer what I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to 1st save the returned XML to a file and then loop back to unset.

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "cache-control: no-cache",
      "postman-token: 28025ee8-1e82-ce60-f6ae-f401118baa1c"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    $fp = fopen(ABSPATH.'jwp.xml', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $response);
    fclose($fp);
  }

  $xml = simplexml_load_file(ABSPATH.'jwp.xml');

  for($i = count($xml->channel->item); $i >= 2; $i--){
    unset($xml->channel->item[$i]);
  }

  $xml->saveXML(ABSPATH.'jwp.xml');

  ?>
  <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/FZ8yNTef.js"></script>
  <center><div id="podcast" align="center"></div></center> 
  <script> 
  var PodcastplayerInstance = jwplayer("podcast"); 
  PodcastplayerInstance.setup({ 
    playlist: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/jwp.xml", 
    androidhls: true, 
    preload: "auto", 
    height: 200, 
    width: 400,
    visualplaylist:false,
    stretching: "fill",
      "plugins": {
          "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/listy.js":{},
          'viral-2': {'oncomplete':'False','onpause':'False','functions':'All'}
      }
  });
  </script>
```

In case you want the 2nd or 3rd element only, update the above code with the following

```
for($i = count($xml->channel->item); $i >= 3; $i--){
  unset($xml->channel->item[$i]);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($xml->channel->item); $i++){
  unset($xml->channel->item[0]);
}
```

Comment: I have pasted your answer [here](http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/) It says that, file not found.

Comment: Since the copy didn't work, we can have curl instead.

Comment: Use `wp_safe_remote_get()`.

Comment: @Karun Going to try stay tuned.

Comment: @Karun same [error](http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/) again

Comment: @user5447339 it must be there. I think the absolute path to where the file was saved could be different. If you have ftp access, check where the jwp.xml file has been saved to. I'll update new if necessary.

Comment: Ok, it worked. Thanks for the help. I have one more question:

if we input 1 it shows the most recent item and if we input 2 it shows the latest 2 items. 

`for($i = count($xml->channel->item); $i >= 1; $i--){
    unset($xml->channel->item[$i]);
}`


I am wondering if `$i is 2`, it should show **only** 2nd item from the top.

Comment: if `$i is 3`, it should show only 3rd item from the top.

Comment: @user5447339 updated code. it should work properly.

Comment: @Karun are you around ? I have one last question left.

Comment: @karun I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525527/filter-dates-in-php-in-accordance-with-timezone-selected-from-ui). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse your XML file for creating a playlist for jwplayer according to this [**page**](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#playlist). But there is a problem. `jwplayer:image` and `jwplayer:source` strings cant resolve with `simple_xml_load()` for parsing.

I create a code for you. Code needs `file_get_contens()` function enabled by the server (because we must change remote XML and resolve the `jwplayer:image` problem).

Here is the code;

```php
$source_xml   = 'http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml';
$fileContents = file_get_contents( $source_xml );
$fileContents = str_replace( array( 'jwplayer:image', 'jwplayer:source', ' file="', '" />' ), array( 'image', 'file', '>', '</file>' ), $fileContents );
$fileContents = trim( str_replace( '"', "'", $fileContents ) );
$simpleXml    = simplexml_load_string( $fileContents );
$json         = json_encode( array( $simpleXml->channel->item[0], $simpleXml->channel->item[1] ) );

print( $json );
```

This code resolves your XML file and parses only first two sources for creating playlist items. You can test with your localhost. The result should be like this;

```
[
  {
    "title": "April 4, 2019",
    "description": "The Prime Minister defends the removal of two former cabinet ministers from the Liberal caucus. Jane Philpott and Jody Wilson-Raybould speak out about the Prime Ministers' decision. Members of the \"Daughters of the Vote\" turn their backs on the Prime Minister, and walk out on Andrew Scheer.",
    "image": "http://media.cpac.ca/_app_images/tip_player_poster.png",
    "file": "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/1554372812.mp3"
  },
  {
    "title": "April 3, 2019",
    "description": "Jody Wilson-Raybould and Jane Philpott are removed from the Liberal Caucus. Gerald Butts submits text messages, and other evidence, to the justice committee. The Environment Commissioner says Canada isn't doing enough to fight climate change. ",
    "image": "http://media.cpac.ca/_app_images/tip_player_poster.png",
    "file": "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/1554286033.mp3"
  }
]
```

Best regards